# Can't drop UNDO TABLESPACE

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, rac

We have Oracle 11gR1 RAC two instances on two different servers, new undo tablespace **UNDOTBS20140508** created 30G, I want to remove the old one **UNDOTBSX02**, I did the following:

```
CREATE UNDO TABLESPACE UNDOTBS20140508  DATAFILE '+DATA/....../UNDOTBS20140508' SIZE 20G;
ALTER SYSTEM SET UNDO_TABLESPACE = UNDOTBS20140508;
DROP TABLESPACE UNDOTBSX02 INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES;
```

When trying to drop the **UNDOTBSX02** it show the following error:

> ```
> Error starting at line : 13 in command -
> DROP TABLESPACE UNDOTBSX02 INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES
> Error report -
> SQL Error: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
> ORA-06512: at line 57
> ORA-30013: undo tablespace 'UNDOTBSX02' is currently in use
> 00604. 00000 -  "error occurred at recursive SQL level %s"
> *Cause:    An error occurred while processing a recursive SQL statement
>            (a statement applying to internal dictionary tables).
> *Action:   If the situation described in the next error on the stack
>            can be corrected, do so; otherwise contact Oracle Support.
> ```

I checked **UNDOTBSX02** for any pending transaction and it is empty.
So how to drop it?

**Note** : I am not Oracle DBA, but I have to do this task.

Comment: Hello,  How do you know there is no transaction using the old undo tbs?  Maybe you have to just wait for undo retention. Could you do a restart of the database?

Comment: As @eliatou says, probably a retention problem. http://www.oracleflash.com/32/Change-or-switch-undo-tablespace-in-Oracle-database.html sums it up

Comment: No any connected session
         SELECT a.name,b.status , d.username , d.sid ,     d.serial# FROM   v$rollname a,v$rollstat b, transaction c , v$session d WHERE  a.usn = b.usn AND a.usn = c.xidusn AND c.ses_addr = d.saddr AND a.name IN (  SELECT segment_name FROM dba_segments WHERE tablespace_name = 'UNDOTBSX02');

Comment: ok, no more transaction. Which retention time ?  SQL> sho parameter UNDO_RETENTION.   Could you restart your database?

Comment: You could shutdown db, start it up in restricted mode and then try to drop old tablespace.

Comment: UNDO_RETENTION is 900, and it is live database i cant shut it down.

Comment: How much time was between the ALTER and the DROP tablespace ? Surely, you didn't think that the old UNDO was unused, the second you would perform the mentioned ALTER command, would you ? What is the actual target here, do you need the new UNDO to be active, or do you need to reclaim space used by the old UNDO. When would there be a database restart ? What about backups, surely you have one, before any attempt to drop anything. Right ?

Answer (score 3):

I tried the above suggestions, but did not work, such as select SQL did not get results and I still cannot drop the undo table space.  The fundamental issue is that the old undo table space is still registered in Oracle as its undo, therefore we need to change it to the new undo table space.

Here are what I did and it worked:

1. create a new UNDO table space:

```sql
CREATE SMALLFILE UNDO TABLESPACE "UNDO" 
DATAFILE '+DATA/t2/datafile/undo_01.dbf' SIZE 10G 
REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 500M MAXSIZE 10G;
```

2. Switch the new UNDO to the "official" undo table space:

```sql
alter system set undo_tablespace='UNDO' scope=both;
```

3. drop the old undo table space:

```sql
DROP TABLESPACE UNDOTBS1 INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES;
```

hope this helps.

Comment: This is the same what the original poster tried, and may fail with the same error as long as there is active undo in the original tablespace.

Comment: Not quite. Dave added the option of `scope=both` to his `alter system` statement, which might change the way oracle reacts to the change.

Comment: The scope=both should not change the behaviour as `scope=both` is the default. You have to explicitly state `scope=spfile` or `scope=memory` if you want the change the parameter in only one location.

Answer (score 1):

the error message mean the `tablespace` is in use, and since the undo `tablespace` is critical `tablespace` you need to shut it down first by using:

```
SELECT a.name,b.status , d.username , d.sid , d.serial#
FROM   v$rollname a,v$rollstat b, v$transaction c , v$session d
WHERE  a.usn = b.usn
AND    a.usn = c.xidusn
AND    c.ses_addr = d.saddr
AND    a.name IN ( 
          SELECT segment_name
          FROM dba_segments 
          WHERE tablespace_name = 'UNDOTBSX02'
         );
```

then kill the SID for the undo tablespace by using

```
alter system kill session 'SID,serial'; --change the values of sid and serial by the ones  that being retrived from the previouse command
```

now you should be able to drop it.

Comment: For the select Statement it returns empty result.

Comment: In this case you need to wait until there is no pending transaction then restart instant. and drop it

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to start dropping connections. How do you know what those connections are doing, and what might break if those connections are dropped.

You are better off waiting for sessions to start using the new tablespace. Eventually, the old undo tablespace will be not longer be in use. At that time you can drop it. If you need disk space you can try shrinking the undo tablespace, but that might not work. You can also get downtime to shutdown the database, bring up the database in restrict mode, then drop the old undo tablespace, that shutdown and startup the database unrestricted.

Answer (score 1):

The answers provided by previous posters are all correct regarding the syntax to create a new UNDO tablespace and to switch system to the new UNDO tablespace.

The [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/undo005.htm#ADMIN11476) states that the following statement will switch to the new UNDO tablespace:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET UNDO_TABLESPACE = <name of new UNDO TS>;
```

e.g. for @Mohammad Jolani:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET UNDO_TABLESPACE = UNDOTBS20140508;
```

**However there are some restrictions** to this switching which are documented as:

> The switch operation does not wait for transactions in the old undo tablespace to commit. If there are any pending transactions in the old undo tablespace, the old undo tablespace enters into a PENDING OFFLINE mode (status). In this mode, existing transactions can continue to execute, but undo records for new user transactions cannot be stored in this undo tablespace.
>
> An undo tablespace can exist in this PENDING OFFLINE mode, even after the switch operation completes successfully. A PENDING OFFLINE undo tablespace cannot be used by another instance, nor can it be dropped. Eventually, after all active transactions have committed, the undo tablespace automatically goes from the PENDING OFFLINE mode to the OFFLINE mode. From then on, the undo tablespace is available for other instances (in an Oracle Real Application Cluster environment).

So according to **A PENDING OFFLINE undo tablespace cannot be used by another instance, nor can it be dropped.** you would have to wait until Oracle has fully switched the current UNDO tablespace completely.

Try querying the status of the tablespace with :

```
select file#, ts#, status, bytes, substr(name, 0, 30) from v$datafile;
```

You might find that your old UNDO tablespace is still being used or in the `PENDING OFFLINE` state.

You could also try switching the UNDO tablespaces back and forth with:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET UNDO_TABLESPACE = '';
```

> An undo tablespace can exist in this PENDING OFFLINE mode, even after the switch operation completes successfully. A PENDING OFFLINE undo tablespace cannot be used by another instance, nor can it be dropped. Eventually, after all active transactions have committed, the undo tablespace automatically goes from the PENDING OFFLINE mode to the OFFLINE mode. From then on, the undo tablespace is available for other instances (in an Oracle Real Application Cluster environment).
>
> If the parameter value for UNDO TABLESPACE is set to '' (two single quotes), then the current undo tablespace is switched out and the next available undo tablespace is switched in. Use this statement with care, because if there is no undo tablespace available, the SYSTEM rollback segment is used. This causes ORA-01552 errors to be issued for any attempts to write non-SYSTEM related undo to the SYSTEM rollback segment.

You can not force the switching unless you shut down your database. If Oracle thinks it still needs the old UNDO TS then so be it. Your system will already be writing to the new UNDO TS so there is no need to force anything unless you have special requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Saw [this link](http://dbafix.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-drop-and-recreate-undo.html) for solution. It worked for me!

Corresponding rollback segments need to be offline before you can drop the tablespace.

Also, restarting the database is required before new parameter values take effect.